# Cant format date from database to jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, date, model-view-controller, format

I want to convert my date object from hibernate the format is as follow 2016-07-23 00:00:00.0 so im using a jstl format

```
    <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>

    <c:set var="now" value="${vac.date}"
    <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy"
```

Im trying to format it but seems not to be working im getting this error

WEB-INF/views/details.jsp (line: 34, column: 20) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **version** of JSTL, I hope it is 1.1 or 1.2.

Instead of

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Use

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Old version of JSTL (1.0) URIs **don't** have **jsp**.